# Pointer to all std::vector elements

Tags: c++, arrays, std, c++03

What is the optimal (from code readability and semantics) way to get a pointer to all std::vector elements so it can be used as usual array? I used to use:

```
void Func( int* )

  ...

std::vector<int> x(1000);
Func(&(x[0]));
```

but i wonder is there any prettier way to do this? x.begin() returns vector::iterator.

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing isn't that pretty anyway. Do you really need to mix the two? What happens if the code calls `assign` or `resize` on the vector? Could make your pointer invalid.

Comment: @Component10 Agreed, and I don't know his use case, but the usual reason for needing this is to interact with a legacy API. ([or not so legacy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write))

Comment: @Component10, this is mostly about functions calls. Ones only pointer is given to the functions they can't change vector size:)

Comment: @klm123: Best to obtain the pointer as a parameter to the function call (like `myFunc(&x.front(), ...)`) rather than storing it in a variable. That way, if a reallocation occurs (depending on what you do with your vector) you'll never have an out of date pointer variable.

Comment: Ok. I just described the problem this way.

Comment: @John, as far as I know, vector was guaranteed to have contiguous storage in C++03. string was the one without such guarantee. Source: "Effective STL" by Scott Meyers, item 16: "Know how to pass vector and string data to legacyAPIs

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov:  Duh, you're correct of course.  I'm going on 3 hours sleep...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x.data()` in C++11 or `&x.front()` in C++03

Comment: You can also just do `&x[0]`, just like with a regular array.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Dave's answers, you can leave out the parentheses:

```
int * xP = &x[0];
```

Which is really as short as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it this way: `int * xp = &x.front()`, but there is no optimal solution for this , everything you write should be optimized into the same result by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is guaranteed to have contigious storage in C++11， and also in platforms from vc++6.0 to vc++ 2012.

Comment: A `std::vector` already had continuous storage before C++11. It's `std::string` that was muddy in that regard.